# How can I create a function that generates an empty vector and then populate it with results of a for-loop?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am trying to convert the following for-loop into a function where I can vary sample size.

This code pulls 500 random samples between 1-365 and assesses if the value '1' exists. If 1 exists then the result of the 'all' function is FALSE. The for-loop then runs this 1000 times and populates the empty vector t.

```
t <- vector()

for (i in 1:1000){
  t[i] <- all(ifelse(data.frame(table(sample(1:365, 500, replace=TRUE)))$Var1 == 1, FALSE, TRUE))
}

t
```

I want to write a custom function based off this that allows me to vary the sample size. This is what I have so far.

```
t <- vector()

function.a <- function(sample.size){
  for (i in 1:1000){
  t[i] <- all(ifelse(data.frame(table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)))$Var1 == 1, FALSE, TRUE))
}
  return(t)
}

function.a(500)
```

Is there any way to include the generation of an empty vector such as 't' in the function and condense this a little more?

Edited code as per feedback from u/r2evans :

```
function.a <- function(sample.size){
  t <- vector()  
  for (i in 1:1000){
  t[i] <- all(ifelse(data.frame(table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)))$Var1 == 1, FALSE, TRUE))
}
  return(t)
}

function.a(500)
```

Edit 2: Final code

```
function.a <- function(sample.size){
  x <- vector()
  for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- !any(data.frame(table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)))$Var1 == 1)
}
  return(x)
}

function.a(750)
```

Edit: Final final answer!

```
x <- vector(length = 1000)

for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- !any(sample(1:365, 500, replace=TRUE) == 1) 
}

function.a <- function(sample.size){
  x <- vector(length= 1000)
  for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- !any(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE) == 1) 
}
  return(x)
}
function.a(750)
```

Comment: Don't create a variable *outside* of the function and then change/update that variable *inside* the function; while it can work, it's bad practice for several reasons. Foremost: its "side-effect" operations makes troubleshooting more difficult, and makes it easy to make non-reproducible results. It's often best (in functional programming) to use only what was passed as an argument, only generate what you don't know from that.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actionable part of your comment is, do I leave it as is or am I changing my approach? I'm new to loops so thanks for the patience!

Comment: *Move `t <- vector()` inside the function.* (Also, your use of `ifelse` is completely unnecessary; use `t[i] <- !all(data.frame(...)$Var1==1)`.)

Comment: Removing the ifelse degenerates my code so that it "only" returns TRUE values now. I wrote the code such that, If value 1 exists then there will be a single FALSE value the list Var1. If value 1 doesn't exist, then there will only be TRUE values. If there are only TRUE values then the value returned by all is TRUE and FALSE if at least one of the values in Var1 is FALSE. Thus, if the results of the all function is TRUE, then the value 1 does no occur in Var1. I will try your advice about moving the vector inside the function and update my code above.

Comment: I don't know why you see those results. `!all(...)` is logically equivalent to `ifelse(all(...),F,T)`, and is more concise and likely to be infinitesimally faster (`!` should be faster than `ifelse`).

Comment: !any worked but !all did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want `FALSE` if there is atleast one 1 in `table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE))`.

I would have written this as :

```
function.a <- function(sample.size){
  replicate(1000, !any(table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)) == 1))
}
t1 <- function.a(500)
```

Comment: The !any is more elegant than my contrived solution with ifelse and worked unlike the !all suggested earlier, but without including the empty vector and return function in the code it was incomplete. I needed to store the result in a vector so that I could see 1000 results after the loop. Why replicate here instead of the for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- f(x)
}?

Comment: I rarely use `for` loop in R. Most of the time I feel more comfortable with `sapply`/`lapply`. This looked like a good case to use `replicate` since we just want to repeat the same code `n` times.

Comment: So how would you adapt this code with sapply/lapply and store the results of each iteration in a vector as part of a function?

Comment: `t1 <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) !any(table(sample(1:365, 500, replace=TRUE)) == 1))`

Comment: This always returns 1000 FALSE values.

Comment: You need to replace 500 with `sample.size`. There is absolutely no difference between my `replicate` code and `sapply`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225532/discussion-between-myfatson-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: @myfatson Is there any issue that you are facing understanding this?

Comment: Final answer: x <- vector(length = 1000)
for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- !any(sample(1:365, 500, replace=TRUE) == 1) 
} Thanks for the help!